# Error arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, android-ndk, havok

I am trying to compile sample Havok Android games in Visual Studio but I keep getting this error:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: VisSampleApp.cpp:No such file or directory
```

I downloaded the NDK and referenced it in the `PATH`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: You might have better luck in the Havok Project Anarchy forums: http://forum.projectanarchy.com/forumdisplay.php?30-Android-Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It found the compiler under the PATH, could not find the source file.

can you post the query you use to compile ndk lib, android.mk and application.mk?

Comment: what do you mean by query,i just clicked 'build' in visual studio n the errors popped up

Comment: you can't use VS to compile android ndk because they have different toolchain unless you configure to make VS uses the toolchain of android ndk. You need to follow the NDK instruction how to compile it using "ndk-build"

Comment: The simplest hellow-jni program (it is in the sample folder of anroid-ndk) is just open cmd in the jni folder and run the command: ndk-build. This is my example: http://www.screencast.com/t/dAvkn8cLmQ I compiled it by ndk-build with some parameters